# idea on combination and permutation

Tags: probability, statistics

What is the probability of winning a lottery in which you must choose 4 numbers from the numbers 1 through 14? 
a)assuming the order is unimportant
b)assuming the order matters

I already have answered a) I believe it's just $\frac{1}{_{14}C_4} = \frac{1}{1001}$

Im confused on how to answer b. Can someone give an idea on how to do this kind of problem.. I know that this will involve permutation as arrangement matters. But I don't know how to construct the right formula. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) $\displaystyle \frac{1}{14 \choose 4}$, as you correctly stated

b) $\displaystyle \frac{1}{11 \times 12 \times 13 \times 14}$ , that's the number$^{-1}$ of possible extractions. Think about it this way: you have 14 possibilities for the first number, then 13 for the second, and so on.

Comment: Agreed. Just use the permutation instead of the combination.

Comment: thank you so much .. so it's just $\frac{1}{P_r^n}$ ..